# расстановка блоков внутри row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Имеется ряд с 2 блоками:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div="class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">1</div>
        <div="class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, что бы именно второй блок (с цифрой '2' внутри) при уменьшенном экране, то бишь в md размере был всегда сверху первого блока.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блоки надо будет поменять местами и добавить col-<>-push-<> и col-<>-pull-<>.Примерно вот так:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-md-12">2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-md-12">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```